# React using REDUX useSelector error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'projectname')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am getting this error when I load data using useSelector, however it returns the correct information. I gather that the data is loaded after the error, but how can I avoid it?:

[image: using useSelector]

```
           const dispatch = useDispatch();
            const { identify } = useParams();

            //set loader
            const [loaderthis, setLoaderthis] = useState(true);
            const [breadCrumb, setBreadCrumb] = useState("");

            //send identify to REDUX to obtain this ID project
            useEffect(() => {
                if (identify) {
                const fetchData = () => {
                    return dispatch(getProjectById(identify));
                };
                fetchData();
                }
            }, []);

            //get this project from REDUX
            const getProj = useSelector(
                (state: RootState) => state.projectreducer.detail
            );
            //HERE WHEN I LOG getProj i get the data objet right!!!
            console.log(getProj)

            //set loading to false when proyecto is valid
            useEffect(() => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                const fetchBread = async () => {
                    let namePro = getProj.projectname;  //ERROR HERE??
                    return setBreadCrumb(namePro || "");
                };
                fetchBread();
                setLoaderthis(false);
                }, 500);
            }, [loaderthis]);
```

**EDIT:** this is the object it returns

[image: object]

Comment: @slideshowp2 Good! it works! It was so easy I hadn't even thought of it. Thanks a lot! Can you put this as an answer to give it as a valid solution?

Comment: Post as an anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the `getProj` state slice is populated after an API call. So it's undefined before the API call responds, try using the optional chain `getProj?.projectname`; And, add getProj as dependences of `useEffect` hook, so that when getProj changes, the `useEffect` will execute again.